# Connecting my static html Home Page to my react app - Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a created a web app with React. 
The app works as follows:
myappname.herokuapp.com/page/1
myappname.herokuapp.com/page/3

These all work fine.

Now I want to create a nice landing page that explains everything my app does and I want the page to be located at
myappname.herokuapp.com

I have the full page made including html, js and css. I'm trying to figure out how to integrate that static page on my react app. Is it through adding it to my project and linking through the react-router? (This seems weird as the page is html and not a React component in it's own)
Is it through some Heroku configuration?

I'm a bit lost.

P.S: I am using Node.JS with express as the back-end (If the routing needs to come from the server)

Thank you for helping

Comment: You probably want to keep the static page outside of react and just use a normal <a> link to it.

Comment: I agree, However, how do I actually link it? as in, how do I tell my app to take this "Home Page" at the "myapp.herokuapp.com" endpoint and use the react-router configuration for everything else?

I am using node.js on the backend